# Are Birra Moretti Beers from the series "Le regionali" still available?

Tags: specialty-beers, local

Last October, being in Northern Italy I really enjoyed a couple of sorts of Birra Moretti Beers of the [Le regionali](http://www.birramoretti.it/famiglia/le-regionali/) series.

Now, in Southern Italy (Campania) I would like to taste other sorts but I don't see these beers in food shops. Are these beers still available and I just have to go to a bigger grocery store, or were they limited and are not available any more, or are they not available in the South at all?

Comment: Later I have seen "Siciliana" in Rome, but none of other sorts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are still available for sale in Italy when I write, in May 2019: just two days ago I shared with a friend one Moretti *alla Toscana* and one *alla Piemontese*.

*Le Regionali* can mainly be found in local family-run grocery stores or in supermarkets. These beers by Moretti (whose lager is anyway one of the most popular Italian beers in Italy) are not likeky to be found in pubs or restaurants instead. Those - mainly small - restaurants who offer local foodies and drinks in particular may have special beers by Moretti in bottle or from tap also.

Finally, I don't know much about distribution in the south of my country, since I live in northern Italy. Things (and most popular brands) may change significantly county by county but *Le Regionali* are all supposed to be distributed nationwide, not each one in the county inspiring it.

Comment: Yes, the first time I saw them, it was in a small grocery store near Lago di Como, next time was in Rome. Didn't see them in Bologna though :)

Answer (score 3):

Can't tell you shops or supermarkets, but buying in internet should be possible, e.g. here: [bevandeadomicilio.com](http://www.bevandeadomicilio.com/birre-industriali/6338-moretti-le-regionali.html), [trovaprezzi.it](https://www.trovaprezzi.it/prezzo_the-caffe-solubili_birra_moretti_regionali.aspx), [Amazon.it](https://www.amazon.it/Moretti-Birra-Toscana-Cl-50/dp/B00Y8CZ4KC).

I didn't look for sales outside Italy, since you mentioned to be in Southern Italy. Sometimes local people do know more.

Comment: Thanks, that means that the beers are still available. I'm not in Italy anymore but I'll be there in couple of month again. Maybe I'll have more luck this time.